# Trying to convert numerics into coordinates with sf function

Tags: r, spatial

Someone had previously helped me where I was trying to convert numerical values into coordinates and directed me to use the st_as_sf function which another colleague of mine agreed was correct.

```
    Master_Cave_data <- Master_cave_data %>%
    st_as_sf(Master_cave_data, coords = c('lon', 'lat'), crs = 4326)
```

But I kept on getting the issue

```
    Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr, sf_column_name = sf_column_name) : no simple features geometry column present –
```

I know that I need the simple features but am unsure of what to do. Have tried sf_column_name = NULL but that did not work. The numerics I am trying to convert into coordinates are points.

Comment: I do not know about that function but your code looks like it should be `Master_cave_data %>%
    st_as_sf(coords = c('lon', 'lat'), crs = 4326)` You have `Master_cave_data` twice

Comment: I figured I would have to specify the dataset from which lon and lat were originating from

Comment: Please try my version.

Comment: Hi Sorry for delayed response, you were right thank you!